# Turn off Outlook app notifications with GPO

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, notifications

I've been trying to create a GPO that would turn off Outlook 365 notifications that appear on the desktop.  I've tried the Office 2016/365 Administrative Templates but they don't stop the notifications that come from Windows 10 "Notification & actions"

I've been able to turn off all notifications via GPO but this is unacceptable being we use soft phones and need to see these notifications.  I know its possible manually but haven't found a link to a GPO that will work for just the Outlook app.

Any help would be great,  thanks.

Comment: According to my research, I'm afraid there is no such an option in GPO or registry key to disable Outlook in Notification and Actions. There is a setting to hide Windows security app notifications, but this will be applied to all notifications:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-security-center/wdsc-hide-notifications

Comment: Perry,  Thanks for your feedback.  actually I found the registry setting HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Preferences -Name NewmailDesktopAlerts -Value 0 .  Now all I need to do is create a way to modify this setting to a group of ad users.

Comment: As far as I know, you may deploy registry key via GPO: https://thesolving.com/server-room/how-to-deploy-a-registry-key-via-group-policy/